# How can we create subdirectories in Qt project?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I would like to create subdirectories under the main project
The project structure is:

test1_folder:

```
      test1.pro
      core_folder:
                core_folder.pro   
                Headers_folder
                Sources_folder
      gui_folder
                gui_folder.pro
                Headers
                Sources_folders
                Forms (which contains GUI files)
```

To create gui_folder I know that we should select **Application** then **Qt widgets Application** for others I tried all type but it is not working. Can you please help me?

Best Regards,

Comment: Are you looking for [subdirs](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-creating.html#adding-subprojects-to-projects)?

Comment: Yes the link that you gives me is helpful. Thank you